# Trying to follow the tutorial for zf1: about the database connection

Tags: zend-framework

I'm following [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html) tutorial.

When I run `php scripts/load.mysql.php` it says:

> SQLSTATE[42000] [1102] Incorrect database name '/home/tirengarfio/workspace/ZendFW/gaziende/application/../data/db/guestbook-dev.db'

So I just tried to change the line

```
resources.db.params.dbname = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/db/guestbook-dev.db"
```

to

```
resources.db.params.dbname = "guestbook-dev" and created a new database called guestbook.
```

but I get another error about the "guestbook" is not a file, exactly:

> PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/home/tirengarfio/workspace/ZendFW/gaziende/scripts/data.mysql.sql): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/tirengarfio/workspace/ZendFW/gaziende/scripts/load.mysql.php on line 81

This is the code around the line 81 error (checkout what var_dump() returns):

```
// Check to see if we have a database file already
$options = $bootstrap->getOption('resources');
$dbFile  = $options['db']['params']['dbname'];
if (file_exists($dbFile)) {
    unlink($dbFile);
}

// this block executes the actual statements that were loaded from
// the schema file.
try {
    $schemaSql = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/schema.mysql.sql');
    // use the connection directly to load sql in batches
    $dbAdapter->getConnection()->exec($schemaSql);
    var_dump($dbFile);die(); // this returns "guestbook-dev"
    chmod($dbFile, 0666);
```

So.. how should I set the name for the database connection exactly?

Note: the example of the tutorial is for Sqlite and I'm trying to use MySQL. Is that point? I never used Sqlite.

Regards

Comment: there's a simple `realpath($dbFile)` missing - also, make sure that `$schemaSql` does really contain data and that you do not have a typo in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are the basic application.ini settings for a Mysql db,

```
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_Mysql"
resources.db.params.username = "username"
resources.db.params.password = "password"
resources.db.params.dbname = "database name"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true //optional but very helpful if you only have one db
```

Mysql Needs a little more info then SqlLite.

As far as populating the DB for this Tutorial I just took the easy way and copied the SQL into phpmyadmin.

**Note:**
If you've never used SqlLite before, this might be great chance to learn something new. This tutorial really doesn't need Mysql. :)

Comment: the `resources.db.params.charset = "utf-8"` just helped me with a lot of headache and got rid of 20 lines of bootstrapping-code - nice!